# Menu Item InstantiatingTabListener - Android Fragment -

Tags: android

[image: problem in menu items not showing text and icon] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDFyU.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYniI.png

I have written code for showing tab menu in my app. it works fine but in some mobiles tab does not show text and icon as shown in attached image. I am using Fragments.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHelper tabHelper = getTabHelper();

    CompatTab menuTab = tabHelper.newTab("menu").setText(R.string.tab_section1).setIcon(
            R.drawable.home_icon).setTabListener(
            new InstantiatingTabListener(this, MenuFragment.class));

    tabHelper.addTab(menuTab);
```

After lots of triage i found below code has issues

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //nothing xml written for menu 
}
```

So i tried to add below code

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menufav:
            Intent menuintent = new Intent(this, FavouritesFragment.class);
            startActivity(menuintent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

BUT SINCE IT IS FRAGMENT WE CAN NOT USE INTENT. IT THROWS CASTING ERROR.

Now how do I solve this issue? I have below class for click listener. i want to make use of it.

```
 public static class InstantiatingTabListener implements CompatTabListener {

    private final TabCompatActivity mActivity;
    private final Class mClass;

    /**
     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param cls The class representing the fragment to instantiate
     */
    public InstantiatingTabListener(TabCompatActivity activity, Class<? extends Fragment> cls) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mClass = cls;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
        if (fragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            tab.setFragment(fragment);
            ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tab.getTag());
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

Comment: There are no `TabHelper` or `CompatTab` classes in the Android SDK. Perhaps you should discuss your issues with those classes with their developer, whoever that is. "BUT SINCE IT IS FRAGMENT WE CAN NOT USE INTENT. IT THROWS CASTING ERROR." -- the first parameter to your `Intent` constructor is a `Context`, and `startActivity()` is a method on `Context`. Your fragment can get a relevant `Context` by calling `getActivity()`.

Comment: Can you please show me example code for getActivity()? it would be helpful.

Comment: Issue resolved after upgrading android to 4.1.1 :)